# WPF: How to change value and keep binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, attachedbehaviors

I was looking for a way to highlight certain parts of a `TextBlock`'s content.

Since most of the solutions I was finding suggested to write my own control that inherits from `TextBlock` and since I don't like to write my own control for every little bit of extra functionality I tried to put that funktionality in an attached behavior, and I was successful (so I thought).

Here's my code for the behavior:

```
Public NotInheritable Class TextBlockHighlighting

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

#Region " HighlightTextProperty "

    Public Shared HighlightTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightText", GetType(String), GetType(TextBlockHighlighting), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf TextBlockHighlighting.OnHighlightTextPropertyChanged)))

    <AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(GetType(TextBlock))>
    Public Shared Function GetHighlightText(ByVal obj As TextBlock) As String
        Return obj.GetValue(TextBlockHighlighting.HighlightTextProperty)
    End Function

    <AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(GetType(TextBlock))>
    Public Shared Sub SetHighlightText(ByVal obj As TextBlock, ByVal value As String)
        obj.SetValue(TextBlockHighlighting.HighlightTextProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnHighlightTextPropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim tb As TextBlock

        tb = TryCast(sender, TextBlock)

        If (tb Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Error")
        End If

        Call TextBlockHighlighting.Refresh(tb)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " HighlightStyleProperty "

    Public Shared HighlightStyleProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightStyle", GetType(Style), GetType(TextBlockHighlighting), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf TextBlockHighlighting.OnHighlightStylePropertyChanged)))

    <AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(GetType(TextBlock))>
    Public Shared Function GetHighlightStyle(ByVal obj As TextBlock) As Style
        Return obj.GetValue(TextBlockHighlighting.HighlightStyleProperty)
    End Function

    <AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(GetType(TextBlock))>
    Public Shared Sub SetHighlightStyle(ByVal obj As TextBlock, ByVal value As Style)
        obj.SetValue(TextBlockHighlighting.HighlightStyleProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnHighlightStylePropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim tb As TextBlock

        tb = TryCast(sender, TextBlock)

        If (tb Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Error")
        End If

        Call TextBlockHighlighting.Refresh(tb)
    End Sub

#End Region

    Private Shared Sub Refresh(ByVal sender As TextBlock)
        Dim highlight As String
        Dim style As Style
        Dim oldValue As String

        oldValue = sender.Text

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sender.Text) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        sender.Inlines.Clear()
        highlight = TextBlockHighlighting.GetHighlightText(sender)
        style = TextBlockHighlighting.GetHighlightStyle(sender)

        If (style Is Nothing) Then
            style = New Style(GetType(Run))
            style.Setters.Add(New Setter(Run.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green))
            style.Setters.Add(New Setter(Run.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White))
        End If

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(highlight) OrElse (oldValue.IndexOf(highlight, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) < 0) Then
            sender.Text = oldValue
        Else
            Dim index As Integer = oldValue.IndexOf(highlight, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            Dim pos As Integer = 0

            Do While (index >= 0)
                Dim t As String

                t = oldValue.Substring(pos, index - pos)
                sender.Inlines.Add(t)
                pos = index

                t = oldValue.Substring(pos, highlight.Length)
                sender.Inlines.Add(New Run(t) With {.Style = style})
                pos += highlight.Length
                index = oldValue.IndexOf(highlight, pos, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            Loop

            sender.Inlines.Add(New Run(oldValue.Substring(pos)))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's my code for the view model (I leave the code of the RelayCommand-class for your to fill in, I guess everyone is having an implementation of it). You could even get rid of it and call the function `ChangeText` in code behind instead:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _highlightText As String
    Private _text As String
    Private _changeTextCommand As ICommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Me.ChangeText)

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        Me.HighlightText = "lo"
        _text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Property HighlightText As String
        Get
            Return _highlightText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _highlightText = value
            Me.OnPropertyChanged("HighlightText")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Text As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ChangeTextCommand As ICommand
        Get
            Return _changeTextCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub ChangeText()
        _text = "This is another text containing the default highlight text ""lo""."
        Me.OnPropertyChanged("Text")
    End Sub

End Class
```

And finally here's my Xaml for the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="HightlightStyle" TargetType="Run">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hightlight text:" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding HighlightText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   local:TextBlockHighlighting.HighlightText="{Binding HighlightText}"
                   local:TextBlockHighlighting.HighlightStyle="{StaticResource HightlightStyle}" />

        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Change text" Margin="100,5" Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's my problem. When I start this program and hit the button "Change text" without doing anything else before, the text gets changed (like expected).

But when I start the program, change the hightlight text (and therefore the highlighting) and hit the button "Change text" after that, nothing happens.

After a lot of searching and debugging and trying I think the reason for that is, that in my attached behavior I change the `Inlines` collection of the `TextBlock` and that breaks the binding to the `Text` property.

So, how can I change the `Inlines` collection of the `TextBlock` (which itself is not bindable) without breaking the binding to the `Text` property?
Or how can I achieve my goal on other ways?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In C#, we are doing something like: 
`myTextbox.SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, anyValueHere)`, this shouldn't break binding.

Comment: Also, you could add textbox style with binding switching, e.g: <TextBox><Textbox.Style><Style TatgetType="Textbox"><Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text}"/><Style.Triggers><Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"><Setter Property="Text" Value="HighlightText"/></Trigger></Style.Triggers></Style></Textbox.Style></TextBox>

Comment: And one more: You can save Binding, then assign it again, like in C#: 

`BindingExpression bindingExpression =  myTextbox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);`
`Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;` .. some code to change for Highlighted, and then: 
`myTextbox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, parentBinding);`

Comment: With `SetCurrentValue` I would set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock`, but I need to use the `Inlines` property to be able to highlight only parts of the text of the `TextBlock`.
Your style suggestion I can't use, because I only want to highlight parts of the text of the `TextBlock`, not all the text.
And re-setting the binding after I changed the value forces the binding to execute and that removes all the highlighting I just did.

Comment: Can you give us sample of what you want to achive? Maybe this will be helpfull that Inlines can hold collection of  <Run>, which Text property is Bindable.

Comment: So you could make something like: 
   `<TextBlock>
`                                        `<TextBlock.Inlines> <Run Text="{Binding Text}"/>
 `                                           `<Run Text="{Binding HighlightText}" Style="{StaticResource HightlightStyle}"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Inlines>
                                    </TextBlock>`

Comment: If you have a `TextBlock` with a text of "One Two Three" I'd like to be able to highlight just the "Two", maybe because the user looked for "Two" and I want to give him a hint where in a longer text he can find what he was looking for. If the user then looks for "One", "Two" should get unhighlighted and "One" should be highlighted instead.
All this highlighting is changing the `Text` property internally and therefore breaking the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since changing the value of the `Text` property didn't re-highlight anyway and since I couldn't get rid of the mentioned problem, I created my own attached `Text` property that changes the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` and triggers the re-highlighting. If I bind to that property instead of the one provided in the `TextBlock` everything works fine now.